# Error while displaying json data in android look for error

Tags: json

Display error org.json.JSONException and org.json.typemismatch and org.json.getJSONObject after third log.d("Lee", "working").

This is the code for converting json data to properly formated list view for android.

```
public class FlowerJSONParser {

public static List<Flower> parserFeed(String content)

{

try 
{

            Log.d("Lee", "working");

            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(content);

            Log.d("Lee", "working");

            List<Flower> flowerList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0; i< ar.length(); i++)

            {

                Log.d("Lee", "working");

                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("Lee", "working");

                Flower flower = new Flower();

                Log.d("Lee", "working");

                flower.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                flower.setNotes(obj.getString("notes"));


                flowerList.add(flower);
            }
            return flowerList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get JSONObject from JSONArray "ar". So, you must make sure all elements in the array are JSONObject. If not, there must be an exception during convert element to JSONObject.

Please be aware that the element in JSONArray can be any primary type (int/long/boolean...), wrapper class(Integer/Long/Boolean...), String, JSONObject and even another JSONArray.
So, you must confirm the type of element before ar.getJSONObject(i).

Another usage is:
Replace ar.getJSONObject(i) by ar.optJSONObject(i).
In this way, if the element is not a JSONObject, you will get a null instead of an exception.